# Error ORA-01843 when importing table to Sqoop

Tags: java, oracle, apache, hadoop, sqoop

I've already imported a table with 54 million rows to *HDFS* of my *Hadoop Cluster*,  and now, importing from Oracle DB a slice of that table
[I've created a *View*, selecting just a short period. Resulted in 260K rows only]
, i'm getting the error below:

> Error: java.io.IOException: SQLException in nextKeyValue      at
>   org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DBRecordReader.java:277)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:556)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)      at
>   org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)       at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)      at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1709)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: not a valid month

The command used was:

`sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@<my_host:port:instanceia> --username <user> --password <pass> --table <DB.TABLE> --split-by NUM_LINE  --m 10 --target-dir  /user/rodrigo/SLICED_TABLE 2>&1|tee import_tab_menor.txt`

I'm a Hadoop/Hive/Sqoop newbie and this was just for learning, but I really want to know how to solve this.

I thought about creating a *view*, changing *date* data type to string just to import the table, but it can give me inacurate results.

EDIT:

I have discovered that it was an internal DB error in the *view* creation.
THe way I was creating the *view* returned me the results I needed. But it was a wrong method to creating it.

In the query inside Sqoop you need to separate the last `AND \$CONDITIONS`, and the format to send the query to Oracle is `to_date('02/04/16', 'dd/mm/yy')`. And then it worked.

Just to bypass the error, I created a *view* changing the datatype of date field to varchar and for some reason it won't work too.

So I've changed again with `to_number(to_char('02/04/16', 'dd/mm/yy'))` to make it work.

I won't close the question because I want an answer for this problem.
And if I find it, I will share.

Comment: Its says `ORA-01843: not a valid month` in your error message. Looks like you need to check your data for its validity

Comment: @Pushkr Yeah, I've checked the dataand it is the same when I imported previously. Not sure why is this happening.

Comment: _"the data is the same"_ -- right, but that kind of error message means that you have a bug in your `CREATE VIEW`, or a configuration mismatch somewhere. Do you have a String column which contains a date? Or do you apply a WHERE clause on a Date column, using a String literal such as '01-JAN-2000'? Cf. http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01843_not_a_valid_month.htm

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter No, I've created a _View_ with a `Select * from My_Table where DT_F = '02/04/16'`, because the Locale in DB is America/Sao_Paulo. [Like Here](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_dates_and_times)
The field is a DATE, not a string. And I've already imported the whole table, dividing by 10 Mi rows per job and everything fine...

Comment: Did you try with `where DT_F = date'2016-04-02'` to make sure that the *literal* is converted to a date using the ISO format (and Oracle can use an index)? Because maybe it's the *column* which is converted to a string; or maybe it's the *locale of the current session* which is used to parse the date; and maybe your locale is "Sao Paulo" **in your query editor**, but I'm quite sure that JDBC does not enforce that one, which would explain why Oracle tries to parse `02/04/16` as `dd-MMM-yyyy`, hence the error you see.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter The fact I think thats strange:
If I import with the command `sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@<my_host:port:instanceia> --username <user> --password <pass> --table <DB.TABLE> --split-by NUM_LINE --where NUM_LINE < 1000 --m 10 --target-dir  /user/rodrigo/SLICED_TABLE 2>&1|tee import_tab_menor.txt` it works! I'm running right now the query you suggested. Since I got no error messages in less than 500 seconds, I think it worked. Just added `--where 'DT_F='date'2016-04-16'` to my Sqoop Import Command.

Going to wait for results.

Comment: For the record, proper configuration of the "NLS" environment *(National Language Settings)* in Oracle clients has been a pain since -- er, at least 1994, before that I did not know Oracle  :-/

Comment: Beware of Linux shell quotes vs. SQL quotes... I suggest `--where "DT_F=date'2016-04-16'"` so that Linux removes the enclosing double quotes after use, and leaves the inner single quotes for SQL to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was in the way I created the view:

I've created the view using literal format to select date intervals.

Something like

> `DT_F>'02/04/16`

But when I create the *View* using

> `to_date('02/04/16', 'dd/mm/yy')`

the error ORA-01843 don't occur anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for this problem is because you have columns names with key words, for example name a column "key" or "order" (just a dummy example) try import the table like this

--query "select * from DB.TABLE where \$CONDITIONS"

Comment: I got it to work by merging what you said with @SamsonScharfrichter suggestion. Thanks you both.